# Development with offline Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

We are developing a HTML5/Angular web application with a server backend that willb be hosted in MS Azure which will also authenticate via the Azure Active Directory.  However, during development, there is occasionally the need to work offline and disconnected from the internet.  When this happens it is not possible to debug and test the application as it is not possible to reach Active Directory to authenticate.

It is possible to create a local Virtual Machine in VirtualBox with all the necessary AD functionality included and then switch the software to use that local VM in development mode but then Azure AD in release mode?

If it is, what steps/roles etc.. will need to be installed in my local Server VM.

Many thanks

Alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is impossible to use the feature provide by Azure AD without internet connect.

> It is possible to create a local Virtual Machine in VirtualBox with all the necessary AD functionality included and then switch the software to use that local VM in development mode but then Azure AD in release mode?

If you want to use the authentication, you may need to setup your own Identity Provider server when you are working off-line. There are a lot of open source library can help to setup the Identity Provider server like [IndentyServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3), 
[AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server) etc.